# Dynamically load a package in python

Tags: python, python-import, dynamic-import

Suppose I have two nearly identical versions of a python package mymod, ie mymod0 and mymod1. Each of these packages has files **init**.py and foo.py, and foo.py has a single function printme(). Calling mymod0.foo.printme() will print "I am mymod0" and calling mymod1.foo.printme() will print "I am mymod1". So far so good.

But now I need to dynamically import either mymod0 or mymod1. The user will input either 0 or 1 to the script (as variable "index"), and then I can create packageName="mymod"+str(index)

I tried this:

```
module=importlib.import_module(module_name)
module.foo.printme()
```

But I get this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'

How can I specify the the package should now be referred to as module so that module.foo.printme() will work?

UPDATE: So it looks like the easiest solution is to use the exec() function. This way I can dynamically create an import statement like this:

```
cmdname="from mymod%s import foo" % index
exec(cmdname)
```

Then:

```
foo.printme()
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I specify the the package should now be referred to as module so that module.foo.printme() will work?

You have to make sure `<module_name>.__init__` imports `foo` into the module's namespace:

```
#./<module_name>/__init__.py
import foo
```

then you can

```
module=importlib.import_module(module_name)
module.foo.printme()
```

> But now I need to dynamically import either mymod0 or mymod1.

Note this only works the first time because python caches loaded modules. If the module has changed since that start of the program, use the [`reload` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function. Just a word of caution: There are several caveats associated with this, and it may end up not doing what you intended.

> How can I recreate this dynamically?

```
for i in range(0,2):
   module_name = 'mymod%s' % i
   module=importlib.import_module(module_name)
   module.foo.printme()
```

Comment: Ok this is close, but what I want to do is dynamically recreate this import: import mymod0 as mymod. So here mymob now refers to package mymod0. If I do that statically, then I can call mymod0.foo.printme() with no problem. How can I recreate this dynamically?